# Calculated row on datagrid returning wrong value

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I am trying to calculate a total on a row on a datagrid and came up with the following code.

```
   Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim dblQty As Double
    Dim dblPrice As Double

    For index As Integer = 0 To grdNewInvoice.RowCount - 1

        dblQty += Convert.ToDouble(grdNewInvoice.Rows(index).Cells(1).Value)
        dblPrice += Convert.ToDouble(grdNewInvoice.Rows(index).Cells(2).Value)

        grdNewInvoice.Rows(index).Cells(3).Value = dblPrice * dblQty


    Next


End Sub
```

Works well if I only have one row. If I have a second row it adds the values of all the columns like this. Column 1 has a combobox that the user can change the value of the quantity, I want the the total row to recalculate everytime the user changes the value. However, it is not calculating correctly, if I change the value on any of the rows, it adds all of the rows together, like this:

[image]

I change the value on the wine to 4 and it produced the wrong total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `+=` otherwise you aggregate the `qty` and the per `price`.

`9 * $17 = $153`

`9 = 5 + 4,  $17 = $7.00 + $10.00`

Code should be:

```
For index As Integer = 0 To grdNewInvoice.RowCount - 1

    dblQty = Convert.ToDouble(grdNewInvoice.Rows(index).Cells(1).Value)
    dblPrice = Convert.ToDouble(grdNewInvoice.Rows(index).Cells(2).Value)

    grdNewInvoice.Rows(index).Cells(3).Value = dblPrice * dblQty


Next
```